# Java inheritance and generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting

Today i had discussion with my colleague about casting.

Our case:
We have root class

```
abstract class RootFoo<R extends RooFoo> {
   ...
   abstract R getThis();
}
```

and we implement method getThis in subclasses.

To save (in my opinion) unnecessary implementation getThis method in every subclass i showed my solution:

```
abstract class RootFoo<R extends RooFoo> {
   ...
   R getThis() {
       return (R) this;
   }
}
```

Could you help me understand why my idea is wrong?

Comment: The more interesting question is: why does the calling code has to know which Subclass of `RootFoo` will be returned? Why is'nt `RootFoo getThis()` enough?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I will pass it into generics ex. public class FooImpl<FooImpl> {}

Comment: Your idea is buggy because you could create classes `ChildFoo extends RootFoo<Child2Foo>` and `Child2Foo extends RootFoo<ChildFoo>`. Then the call of `Child2Foo foo = new ChildFoo().getThis();`would compile but throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I think that both approaches are incorrect.

Why would you need to cast an object to its own type, while it is already typed to a type that inherits from its parent abstract type?

The method `getThis()` is absolutely senseless, because if you have an instance of an object, it is typed by definition.